# Openstack Juno Charms on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, juju, openstack

I've been having difficulties accessing various pages in Horizon. Part of the problem was described in [Openstack Juno Rabbitmq Charm: Config File Missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553350/openstack-juno-rabbitmq-charm-config-file-missing). The other issue that I've been having was that I could not access, among other things, Project->Compute->Access & Security page. It turned out that keystone charm had not set a proper password for quantum_s3_ec2_nova user. The work around for now is to executed the following, on the keystone server:

```
keystone  user-password-update --pass "admin_password from nova-cloud-controller nova.conf file" quantum_s3_ec2_nova
```

For authentication purposes, I set the following:

```
OS_AUTH_URL=http://keystoneIp:5000/v2.0 && export OS_SERVICE_TOKEN="admin_token from keystone.conf" && export OS_TENANT_NAME="admin" && export OS_USERNAME="admin" && export OS_PASSWORD="From keystone juju charm" && export OS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT=http://keystone.ip:35357/v2.0
```

Cheers,